# UIWebView and Gmail autofill username and password fields

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiweb

UIWebView and Gmail autofill username and password fields
is it possible? I want that the user insert his informatin only the first time

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults for username and password.  Have it check if any value exists for those fields, if not, when the user enters them in, store them using NSUserDefaults.  The next time the app loads, it will check that a value exists, and put that value in the correct fields.